# How to access a function in my MainForm from my DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I have a MainForm class where I have a function to retrieve my settings that are stored in my database.

So far so good.

Then, I have a Plugin (DLL) I load in on startup, but I would like to use the same function to retrieve settings in my DLL.

If I need to access functions in my DLL I would just type `myDLL.function(....)`, but I can't use `MainForm.function` from my DLL, as my DLL doesn't know MainForm.

So how do I pass my settings between my main application and my dll?

Answer (score 4):

Just so you know the terminology, you are looking for "[Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)", or "IoC".

There are multiple ways of implementing this, including [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and callbacks (e.g. delegates) as in Nico's answer. There are also Service Locators (though many consider this to be an "anti-pattern") and Factories.

Personally, I prefer the Dependency Injection approach:

Basically, your DLL (a.k.a. "[class library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx)") needs an object that can perform a function, but it needs someone else (the caller) to implement the actual logic.

So, all you need to do is create an interface in your DLL which defines the kind of object you need:

```
Namespace DLL

    Public Interface IDataRetriever

        Public Function GetData() As Object

    End Interface

End Namespace
```

Then in your MainForm project, which references your DLL, simply create a class which implements this interface:

```
Public Class DataRetriever
    Implements DLL.IDataRetriever

    Public Function GetData() As Object Implements DLL.IDataRetriever.GetData
        //...
        Return New Object()
    End Function

End Class
```

(Note that *any* class can implement the interface, including a class which already exists or even MainForm itself. You don't need to create a new class just for the interface - though make sure that you are following [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).)

Now, when you call the DLL, you can pass it your DataRetriever and your DLL will know what it's dealing with.

```
Namespace DLL

    Public Class Utility

        Public Shared Function DLLFunction( retriever as IDataRetriever )
            retriever.GetData()
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

```
Class MainForm

    Sub Example()

        DLL.Utility.DLLFunction( New DataRetriever() )

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what kind of settings you have.

The cleanest way is probably to retrieve the settings in the main application and pass it (as a parameter) to the DLL. You may want to specify an interface or something for the actual settings data. This common type could be in a project that is referenced by both the DLL and the main application project.

Another way is to pass a delegate. Instead of passing the complete settings data, you pass a delegate to a method that can retrieve the data.

Comment: Passing parameters is definitely a easier than Dependency Injection if that's all that's needed. For more advanced functionality, I'd perfer Dependency Injection over delegates (easier to test, cleaner code, etc.). To each his own, though.